# Pause/resume mediaPlayer on notification sound

Tags: android

It's easy to detect when phone calls come in (via phoneStateListener), but what about other notification sounds, such as email or sms?

On some devices, these notification sounds mute but don't pause any currently running mediaPlayer instances, which is annoying for the user.  Ideally, I'd like to listen for notifications that play sound, pause playback for the duration, and then resume playback afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get notified when another app wants to play audio by registering a callback on [AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html) (this would also handle the case of an incoming call).  Specifically, you can look for `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN`, `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`, and `AUDIOFOCUS_TRANSIENT_LOSS`.  The Android music player source has a good [example](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java;h=7c0bbedbedef49bf4c38ef97fdcd0f1017bf5d35;hb=HEAD) of this.

Comment: Android music player source is here (for my own edification):http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/music;h=b5339a88f2c38b30e9093996c4d6bbebddd5b399;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks!  I added it to my answer.