# Pausing & Resuming music on an interrupt by notification/other sound in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am new to community and just started with android development and I am trying to develop a music app for android.

In most of the media players for android, there is an feature that music is paused when you get a call or any other notification sound is played and music resumes when it ends. I am trying to achieve a similar behaviour.

I got a solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491340/pause-resume-mediaplayer-on-notification-sound) but I am not very clear about how to use it. Also source for Android Player is not available any more.

I have written

```
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int i) {
        Log.d("Focus Changed",""+i);
    }
};
```

just to see behaviour of focus change but don't find a way to use it in my media player.

Can someone please guide on this?

Comment: Have a read through this: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html. You simply need to request focus when playing and abandon it when not.

Comment: Thanks @KenWolf!!! I have already started reading the documentation. Will get in case I am still stuck.